# Keras, maximize custom Loss using differents attributes that y_pred y_true

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a specific question that I didn't find an answer on stackoverflow.

First of all I want to give you a general overview of my problem.

I'm doing a binary classification using CNNs and Images. For each image I have an information associated with them in a csv file.

For simplicity I will call the images in numerical order, and I'll put all the informations in a CSV format.

```
id, images, attribute_1, attribute_2, label
1, image_1.png, 10, 11, 1
2, image_2.png, 8, 19, 1
3, image_3.png, 3, 2, 1
4, image_4.png, 10, 8, 1
```

Reading Keras Documentation I understood that, in order to create a custom loss function, I have to write something like this:

```
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred):
    return some_calculus_with_yTrue_and_yPred
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to pass to `customLoss` more parameters like `attribute_1` and `attribute_2` vectors?
- Is it possibile to know in which one batch we are calculating the loss function? (for examples: 100 samples, with batch size 10, there will be 10 batches in which the loss will be calculated )
- Is it possible to access to `x` vector? For `x` vector I mean the vector that contains the samples passed like training and validations set. Having the `x` vector can be useful in order to get the other information like `attribute_1` and `attribute_2` using hashmaps or similar tools.

My idea is to perform something like this:

```
def customLoss(yTrue,yPred, attribute_1, attribute_2):
     loss = 0
     if yTrue[i] == yPred[i]: 
         loss = attribute_1 + attribute_2
     else: 
          otherwise
     return loss
```

This example is very very simple, but it is only necessary to understand how I would like to use other parameters in order to calculate my custom loss function.

Last but not least, is it possible to specify that higher loss is better than lower? (the opposite of standard approach)

Thank guys.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, I believe the answer is yes:  You can pass more parameters than y_pred, y_true.  The documentation has some examples like "Huber_Loss" with an additional parameter:  https://keras.io/losses/ and you can examine the keras code on github to get the template for similar modified functions:  https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py.

Not too sure I understand questions 2 and 3, although it might be possible to pass the "x vector" as an argument in a modified loss function (like a y_pred), but this is very speculative.

Question 4:  Perhaps multiplying the loss by -1?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Multiplyng by 1 yes, but I just want to know if exist ad inverse loss function. 
For the other answers I'll read the documentation. Thanks

Comment: @AsoStrife It may be the case that you can simply make the "y_true" include the label _and_ the attributes in one array which is passed into the model.fit() call.  Since you are creating your own loss function, I presume you'll be able to untangle the components within the loss function as needed.  Additionally, you might need to create a custom accuracy metric which ignores the attributes.  I hope this helps.